# Flutter: How can I get all documents name of a collection in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I make an app in Flutter with Firestore now I would go through all documents in a collection and I want to get the document name (id) and the field of the documents and do something with that. I have already make a listview where the data is displayed but I can't do something with that, for example, add it to a list or something.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is kind of vague.  What exactly are you stuck on?  Have you read the documentation and seen sample code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that by getting list of documents like:

```
final QuerySnapshot result =
          await Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
```

And after that you can iterate this list and get data:

```
documents.forEach((data) => print(data));
```

Comment: I can't use `getDocuments()`. It raises an error `The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference`

Comment: as for 2021 the getDocument methods is already changed to get()

Answer (score 8):

First, make the reference of Firestore

```
final userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
```

Second, make iterator to get all document from fireStore

```
 userRef.getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc.data);
      });
    });
```

- you can get specific data like email as an example :

```
print(doc.data['email'];
```

- you can get document Id by

```
print(doc.documentID);
```

- can check if the document exists or not by

```
print(doc.exists);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an updated answer.
Recently `getDocuments` is deprecated by firebase in flutter.

Instead of that we can use `get` to query all the documents inside the collection.

like this

```
final QuerySnapshot result =
      await Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').get();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;
```

and to list out all the document you just need to loop the documents list like this

```
documents.forEach((DOC) => print(DOC.data()));
```

Comment: this should be marked as answer since it is up to date

Comment: how to get the ID's of these documents?

Comment: Will we be charged for all the documents or it will be counted as 1 read ?

Comment: Last line should be `documents.forEach((data) => print(data.data()));`

Answer (score 3):

as *Shubham* said the `getDocuments` it's now deprecated,so if you just want to return the names of the documents you should do this :

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var result=await db.collection('Pets').get();
result.docs.forEach((res) {print(res.id); });
```

Also you can print especific ones using `where` like this:

```
var result=await db.collection('Pets').where("sex",whereIn:["Male"] ).get();
result.docs.forEach((res) {print(res.id); });
```

This work for me, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data efficiently by listening to the data using streams.

Start by getting the reference for the Firestore:

```
final userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
```

With the following function, you will be subscribing to the data coming from Firestore. Meaning each time there is a modification in your collection, Firestore will notify your app automatically (the code where you are listening for changes will re-run every time your app gets notified).

In the first for-loop, you are listening for changes within your collection, looping through the snapshots. The second for-loop, will loop through the `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`, so you can have access to the documents for each snapshot.

```
void getData() async {
 await for (var snapshot in userRef.snapshots()) {
  for(var document in snapshot.docs()) {
    print(document.data()); //You'll get printed the whole data
    print(document['email']); //You'll get printed the email field.
    print(document.id); //You'll get printed the document ID
  }
 }
```

Hint: You can test the streaming by changing something within your collection, directly on Firebase website.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').getDocuments();
```

before 2021 but now you should mention as below :

```
     final querySnap = await firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').get();


    for (var i = 0; i < querySnap.docs.length; i++) {
        final data = querySnap.docs[i].id;
        log(data.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also get documents name by wrapping a widget with **FutureBuilder**
like so:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("collection_name")
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  QuerySnapshot documents = snapshot.data;
                  List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = documents.docs;
                  docs.forEach((data) {
                    print(data.id);
                  });
                } else {
                  print("nodata");
                }
                return Container();
              })
```